# How to make a request using graphql-go

Tags: go, graphql, graphql-go

I need to make a request to an external API which uses GraphQL using Go. To do so, I'm using the following client: https://github.com/graphql-go/graphql but the documentation is very limited and don't quite understand how to perform the request. My request is a simple mutation but again, don't know how to perform it.

Comment: The go `graphql` package has extensive examples e.g. the TODO app: https://github.com/graphql-go/graphql/blob/master/examples/todo/main.go

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CRUD example extracted from [here](https://github.com/graphql-go/graphql/tree/master/examples/crud).

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "math/rand"
    "net/http"
    "time"

    "github.com/graphql-go/graphql"
)

// Product contains information about one product
type Product struct {
    ID    int64   `json:"id"`
    Name  string  `json:"name"`
    Info  string  `json:"info,omitempty"`
    Price float64 `json:"price"`
}

var products = []Product{
    {
        ID:    1,
        Name:  "Chicha Morada",
        Info:  "Chicha morada is a beverage originated in the Andean regions of Perú but is actually consumed at a national level (wiki)",
        Price: 7.99,
    },
    {
        ID:    2,
        Name:  "Chicha de jora",
        Info:  "Chicha de jora is a corn beer chicha prepared by germinating maize, extracting the malt sugars, boiling the wort, and fermenting it in large vessels (traditionally huge earthenware vats) for several days (wiki)",
        Price: 5.95,
    },
    {
        ID:    3,
        Name:  "Pisco",
        Info:  "Pisco is a colorless or yellowish-to-amber colored brandy produced in winemaking regions of Peru and Chile (wiki)",
        Price: 9.95,
    },
}

var productType = graphql.NewObject(
    graphql.ObjectConfig{
        Name: "Product",
        Fields: graphql.Fields{
            "id": &graphql.Field{
                Type: graphql.Int,
            },
            "name": &graphql.Field{
                Type: graphql.String,
            },
            "info": &graphql.Field{
                Type: graphql.String,
            },
            "price": &graphql.Field{
                Type: graphql.Float,
            },
        },
    },
)

var queryType = graphql.NewObject(
    graphql.ObjectConfig{
        Name: "Query",
        Fields: graphql.Fields{
            /* Get (read) single product by id
               http://localhost:8080/product?query={product(id:1){name,info,price}}
            */
            "product": &graphql.Field{
                Type:        productType,
                Description: "Get product by id",
                Args: graphql.FieldConfigArgument{
                    "id": &graphql.ArgumentConfig{
                        Type: graphql.Int,
                    },
                },
                Resolve: func(p graphql.ResolveParams) (interface{}, error) {
                    id, ok := p.Args["id"].(int)
                    if ok {
                        // Find product
                        for _, product := range products {
                            if int(product.ID) == id {
                                return product, nil
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    return nil, nil
                },
            },
            /* Get (read) product list
               http://localhost:8080/product?query={list{id,name,info,price}}
            */
            "list": &graphql.Field{
                Type:        graphql.NewList(productType),
                Description: "Get product list",
                Resolve: func(params graphql.ResolveParams) (interface{}, error) {
                    return products, nil
                },
            },
        },
    })

var mutationType = graphql.NewObject(graphql.ObjectConfig{
    Name: "Mutation",
    Fields: graphql.Fields{
        /* Create new product item
        http://localhost:8080/product?query=mutation+_{create(name:"Inca Kola",info:"Inca Kola is a soft drink that was created in Peru in 1935 by British immigrant Joseph Robinson Lindley using lemon verbena (wiki)",price:1.99){id,name,info,price}}
        */
        "create": &graphql.Field{
            Type:        productType,
            Description: "Create new product",
            Args: graphql.FieldConfigArgument{
                "name": &graphql.ArgumentConfig{
                    Type: graphql.NewNonNull(graphql.String),
                },
                "info": &graphql.ArgumentConfig{
                    Type: graphql.String,
                },
                "price": &graphql.ArgumentConfig{
                    Type: graphql.NewNonNull(graphql.Float),
                },
            },
            Resolve: func(params graphql.ResolveParams) (interface{}, error) {
                rand.Seed(time.Now().UnixNano())
                product := Product{
                    ID:    int64(rand.Intn(100000)), // generate random ID
                    Name:  params.Args["name"].(string),
                    Info:  params.Args["info"].(string),
                    Price: params.Args["price"].(float64),
                }
                products = append(products, product)
                return product, nil
            },
        },

        /* Update product by id
           http://localhost:8080/product?query=mutation+_{update(id:1,price:3.95){id,name,info,price}}
        */
        "update": &graphql.Field{
            Type:        productType,
            Description: "Update product by id",
            Args: graphql.FieldConfigArgument{
                "id": &graphql.ArgumentConfig{
                    Type: graphql.NewNonNull(graphql.Int),
                },
                "name": &graphql.ArgumentConfig{
                    Type: graphql.String,
                },
                "info": &graphql.ArgumentConfig{
                    Type: graphql.String,
                },
                "price": &graphql.ArgumentConfig{
                    Type: graphql.Float,
                },
            },
            Resolve: func(params graphql.ResolveParams) (interface{}, error) {
                id, _ := params.Args["id"].(int)
                name, nameOk := params.Args["name"].(string)
                info, infoOk := params.Args["info"].(string)
                price, priceOk := params.Args["price"].(float64)
                product := Product{}
                for i, p := range products {
                    if int64(id) == p.ID {
                        if nameOk {
                            products[i].Name = name
                        }
                        if infoOk {
                            products[i].Info = info
                        }
                        if priceOk {
                            products[i].Price = price
                        }
                        product = products[i]
                        break
                    }
                }
                return product, nil
            },
        },

        /* Delete product by id
           http://localhost:8080/product?query=mutation+_{delete(id:1){id,name,info,price}}
        */
        "delete": &graphql.Field{
            Type:        productType,
            Description: "Delete product by id",
            Args: graphql.FieldConfigArgument{
                "id": &graphql.ArgumentConfig{
                    Type: graphql.NewNonNull(graphql.Int),
                },
            },
            Resolve: func(params graphql.ResolveParams) (interface{}, error) {
                id, _ := params.Args["id"].(int)
                product := Product{}
                for i, p := range products {
                    if int64(id) == p.ID {
                        product = products[i]
                        // Remove from product list
                        products = append(products[:i], products[i+1:]...)
                    }
                }

                return product, nil
            },
        },
    },
})

var schema, _ = graphql.NewSchema(
    graphql.SchemaConfig{
        Query:    queryType,
        Mutation: mutationType,
    },
)

func executeQuery(query string, schema graphql.Schema) *graphql.Result {
    result := graphql.Do(graphql.Params{
        Schema:        schema,
        RequestString: query,
    })
    if len(result.Errors) > 0 {
        fmt.Printf("errors: %v", result.Errors)
    }
    return result
}

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/product", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        result := executeQuery(r.URL.Query().Get("query"), schema)
        json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(result)
    })

    fmt.Println("Server is running on port 8080")
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}
```

### Create

`http://localhost:8080/product?query=mutation+_{create(name:"Inca Kola",info:"Inca Kola is a soft drink that was created in Peru in 1935 by British immigrant Joseph Robinson Lindley using lemon verbena (wiki)",price:1.99){id,name,info,price}}`

### Read

- Get single product by id: `http://localhost:8080/product?query={product(id:1){name,info,price}}`
- Get product list: `http://localhost:8080/product?query={list{id,name,info,price}}`

### Update

`http://localhost:8080/product?query=mutation+_{update(id:1,price:3.95){id,name,info,price}}`

### Delete

`http://localhost:8080/product?query=mutation+_{delete(id:1){id,name,info,price}}`